# Flash in custom camera android

Tags: java, android, camera

There is a custom camera implementation in android on this link http://store.ovi.com/content/147853?clickSource=search&pos=1 I wish to know how we can have flash on while capturing images, is it something we will do ourself ? or any api to set camera mode in the example ?

Please help !

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the desired flash mode as part of the parameters you pass in the `Camera` object using [`setParameters(Camera.Parameters params)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setParameters%28android.hardware.Camera.Parameters%29). Refer to the [`setFlashMode(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setFlashMode%28java.lang.String%29) method on the parameters, supplying either [`FLASH_MODE_ON`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_ON), [`FLASH_MODE_OFF`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_OFF) or [`FLASH_MODE_AUTO`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_AUTO).

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters params = new Camera.Parameters();
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
// ... set other parameters
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: But i have a doubt that this method doesnt work in all versions like above 2.2 or something , but will check

Comment: Well, since `setFlashMode(String)` has been around since API level 5, it should be supported on devices running Android 1.6 or newer (basically all devices out there). However, I imagine there may be limitations in terms of drivers implemented by the hardware manufacturer - not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively easy after you have an instance of the Camera (Camera.open() will return a Camera instance).

First you need to get the Camera Parameters with

```
Camera.Parameters params = yourCameraInstance.getParameters();
```

Next you need to check if the device being used is capable of the flash mode you wish to implement, just in case you try to tell the device to turn on the flash and it can't. This would cause a crash.

```
 List<String> flashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
```

This returns a list of all the flash modes the device is capable of in String form. For example, the list should contain something like: FLASH_MODE_AUTO, FLASH_MODE_ON, FLASH_MODE_OFF, ect.

Then do something like:

```
 if (flashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)) {
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    }
```

Finally, set your new params to your camera instance like so:

```
yourCameraInstance.setParameters(params);
```

---

Likewise, you can check for other camera features in the same fashion:

```
    List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    }
    yourCameraInstance.setParameters(params);
```

Hope this helps someone!